# How to test if file constructor (new File) is supported by browser /w Modernizr?

Tags: javascript, modernizr, html5-filesystem

Im using `new File([_blob], fileName);` to create a file from a blob. This doesn't work in Safari and InternetExplorer.

How to test if the file constructor isnt available? Im using Modernizr 3.0.1

I found the following function, which gives me false on Safari. Is this the right one, also for Internet Explorer?

```
Modernizr.filesystem
```

*Sorry if this is a stupid question but I didn't find any detailed description for the Modernizr tests. It just says "Filesystem API"*

Comment: I get false for Safari, IE 9, 10, 11 and Edge which is the correct behaviour. All of this browsers doesn't support File constructor, according to caniuse.com/#feat=fileapi